# where should I use onPause and onDestroy when using sensors?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm developing app that is using every single sensor in mobile. Now I want to stop their work and updates when I'm pausing or closing app to save battery.

Now for example I use Camera in ActivityA and GPS in ActivityB. Should stoping work of both sensors should be placed in one class or I just need to stop sensors connected with each Activity ?

Comment: You should not rely on `onDestroy` to ever be called. Stopping threads and freeing resources should be done in `onPause` or `onStop`. Just keep in mind when each of them is called. `onPause` is called every time your activity leaves the foreground and `onStop` is called every time your app is killed for whatever reason.

Note: `onPause` and `onStop` are never called if your app is `finish()`ed from `onCreate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite follow. If one Activity uses GPS then you handle starting/stoping this function in this activity. Same with other sensors...you should start and release them during `onStart()` and `onStop()`

Comment: If I understand you correct I need to handle sensors from start to end or from pause to resume in activity that called them. There should ve no global class/place to handle everything?

Comment: You can have global class where you access methods which initialize these sensors but you should call them in activities lifecycle's methods. E.g. when you require GPS updates, you start listening for updates in onStart() and release resources during onStop() to save battery life.